# Should I use a Delegate or a Method in .NET when it only depends on the parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates

Everytime I need a very small Method that only uses its parameters...

**Should I use declare a Delegate or a Method**?

Eg: Multiply three numbers

```
Func<int, int, int, int> Multiply = (a,b,c) => a*b*c;
```

and

```
int Multiply(int a, int b, int c) 
{
    return a*b*c;
}
```

**Edit:**

I want to focus this question in terms of eficiency when compiling, and readability.

Comment: That would entirely depend on the context. For one offs I would use a lambda construct, if the method is going to be called often at different call sites then I would make it a proper method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't declare a delegate rather than a method just for the sake of it. If you're just to call this directly from other code in your class, a method is more idiomatic. If it doesn't need to use any instance variables, you may want to make it a static method to make that clear.

On the other hand, if you only ever need to use it as a delegate, use a lambda expression to create that delegate (as per your first example).

If you want to call it directly *and* use it as a delegate, you can use a method group conversion to create a delegate easily:

```
int d = Multiply(a, b, c); // Normal method invocation
DoSomethingWithFunction(values, Multiply); // Method group conversion
```

Comment: @John, when you say `use a lambda expression to create that delegate`... what exactly do you mean? Am I not using it?

Comment: @Oscar: Your first example uses a lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

Declare private static function if it uses only its own parameters.
By declaring it static, you explicitly tell the future reader of your code (possibly you in a few months) that it's practically independent from the class it's defined in.

Lambdas and anonymous methods can be used as event handlers (bear in mind that it can cause memory leaks when used inappropriately) when it's clear what they do and moreover, they usually will not be reused.

Comment: @Oscar: I clarified it a bit.

Comment: I see. I deleted my comment ;)